# SVG cannot display on Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, mozilla

As the title, the below SVG can't be displayed in Chrome and Mozilla.

Below is my code:

```
document.write("<span style='color:red;'>Some Words...</span>
                <svg height='100' width='100'>
                     <circle cx='50' cy='40' r='35' stroke='black' stroke-width='0' fill='#01916f' />
                </svg>
                <svg height='35' width='50'>
                     <text x='-80' y='-8'  span style='font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;' fill='white'>" + daysLeft + "</text>
                </svg> 
                <svg height='60' width='50'>
                     <text x='-60' y='7'><tspan dy='10' fill='red'>more days to go!</tspan></text>
                </svg> ");
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Newlines aren't allowed as literals inside a JS string but must be encoded with `\n`.

To improve readability and thus maintainability, I'd recommend to split the string into individual lines concatenating them into the final code or writing them line by line.

If you do so, your dynamic content displays perfectly well (up to the improper dimensioning of your text boxes) in chrome 34 and firefox 28.

There is an alternative solution that allows you to stash lexical representations of document fragments in the canonical way. Use data islands (original source: [xml data islands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) on MDN; this article discusses xml data islands only and refers to mozilla. however, the method works as well in chrome and with plain text islands) for this purpose, ie. `script` tags of type `text/plain` (`application/xml`) which contain your html/svg/xml code. these section are accessible through js. There are 1 1/2 drawbacks:

- dynamic content needs to be substituted (in you case: `daysLeft` variable.
- [only if you are using *xml* data islands, eg. for preprocessing before insertion] the content needs to be well-formed xml. valid svg will fulfil this requirement by design, html doesn't necessarily.

Check out live demos of both variants:

- traditional: [see here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.svg.written.html)
- plain text data islands: [see here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.svg.written.textisland.html)
- xml data islands: [see here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.svg.written.xmlisland.html)

Comment: When I check out the live demos at chrome and Mozilla, it does not work.

Comment: They work fine with me on chrome 34, ff 28, ios. part of the text doesn't show but that is due to the dimensioning of the text boxes. Do you get any messages on the console (eg. ctrl+j in chrome) ?

Comment: After some modifying I already get the result that I want, but currently I'm facing some text is not show as you said the dimensioning of the boxes, how to modify the text boxes which contain my circle? Because I found out seem a transparent square boxes is covered my words.